# Running different Firefox Profiles in specific OS X Spaces

Tags: macos, firefox, shell, applescript, osx-snow-leopard

I wonder if it is possible in applescript to create a script for which the results appear in a specific Spaces number, N.

I find since I have many Firefox windows opened at once, it would be nice to have each group of windows be its own identity and open up in a space specific for it.  For instance, Social Networking and E-mail on 1, VPN on 2, iTunes on 3, on-line videos on 5, automotive research on 6, etc.

Currently, I use AppleScript to bind the Profile name to the Firefox invocation:

```
do shell script "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -no-remote -P " & (ASCII character 34) & "Music Stuff" & (ASCII character 34) & " http://www.mymusicweb.com/ &"
```

Here, I want to create a window for Space 7 that invokes the "Music Stuff" Profile and initializes the window to show the My Music Web website.

The problem is, how do I make this only appear in Space 7.

I tried using the Spaces dialog, but when I select my AppleScript executable, it just comes up as FSlauncher, and *every AppleScript comes up as FSlauncher*, so I can't assign them to different spaces.  Likewise, if I used the example of Ned Deily:

> In OS X 10.5 or 10.6, Spaces
>   assignments can be accessed and
>   changed via the scriptable interface
>   to System Events.app:
>
> ```
> tell application "System Events"
>     set x to application bindings of spaces preferences of expose preferences
>     set x to {|com.apple.textedit|:4} & x  -- Have TextEdit appear in space 4
>     set application bindings of spaces preferences of expose preferences to x
> end tell If you don't already know it,
> ```
>
> you can get the bundle id of an application from the Finder:
>
> ```
> tell application "Finder"
>     get id of application file "TextEdit" of folder "Applications" of startup disk
> end tell
> ```

I find that all scripts come up with an id of **aplt**, again with now way to differentiate!

Does anyone else have an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Think i had a similar problem. I wanted to have a separate Firefox window visible on a spaces but [afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/) and other hacks don't work with Firefox. So i messed around and got something working, have a look att https://github.com/wader/firefox-all-spaces if your interested. Easiest is probably to download the whole repos as a zip and follow the instructions.

Comment: Nice, but not exactly what I was looking for.  The idea is to tie a specific space to a specific window.  This app is close in that it can create a unique app which can be treated as bound to a specific window, and could be tweaked to bind it to a specific space in the Spaces & Expose preferences, but would only create 1 window-specific app; I need about 7 unique space-specific apps: EV, Writing, Gaming, Productivity, Finance, Development, etc.

Comment: I guess you could create 7 unique apps that uses different Firefox profiles. Maybe thats what you meant? could work but is really messy, not to mention having to tweak the spaces preferences every restart :(